# can we share the screen with jxbrowser?

Tags: jxbrowser

We are currently working on a web application for teleconsultation, and we have added screen sharing functionality, but when we try to share the screen with jxbrowser it doesn't work (it works with other browsers).
is there a solution?
kind regards.

Comment: Welcome to SO, are you getting any error messages? if yes, do share

Comment: we have any logs

Answer (score 1):

JXBrowser now supports the chromium screen sharing feature, see: https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/release-notes/2021/v7-20.html#screen-sharing